# Unable to delete a row from a UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm getting a compile time error when I attempt to delete a row from my UITableView.  The Table View has 2 sections.  What's the proper code in the commitEditingStyle function to delete a row out of a particular section?

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            var index : Int = indexPath.row
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                indexPath.section
                tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                println("You're in section 0 and row # : \(indexPath.row)")
            } else {
            tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            println("You're in section 1 and row # : \(indexPath.row)")
            }
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
```

The compile error is as follows:

```
2015-05-03 13:18:00.453 TableViewTutorial[6927:126624] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:1582
2015-05-03 13:18:00.459 TableViewTutorial[6927:126624] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001006d9a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102231bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001006d98da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000100b74b6f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010104157a -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 11746
    5   TableViewTutorial                   0x00000001004e2cd7 _TFC17TableViewTutorial14ViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView18commitEditingStyleOSC27UITableViewCellEditingStyle17forRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 2391
    6   TableViewTutorial                   0x00000001004e2f47 _TToFC17TableViewTutorial14ViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView18commitEditingStyleOSC27UITableViewCellEditingStyle17forRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 87
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000101065604 -[UITableView animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 130
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000101045a75 __52-[UITableView _swipeActionButtonsForRowAtIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 72
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100f6da22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000101074e50 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010107421f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010131be80 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 9487
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000100fb3856 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000100fb4483 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000100f80fb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000100f8e227 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17700
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000100f6923c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010060ec91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100604b5d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100604194 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100603bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001047e2a58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000100f6c580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    24  TableViewTutorial                   0x00000001004ead4e top_level_code + 78
    25  TableViewTutorial                   0x00000001004ead8a main + 42
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102a0d145 start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table gets filled by the tableView's underlying `datasource`. When you delete a row in the table you need to make sure to delete that record in the datasource too.

After the delete operation the number of records in the datasource and the number of rows in the table must match again.

Answer (score 0):

You have two sections and a single data source. Deleting one row in section 0 or 1 results in deletion of the row from the source and removing a row in that section, but the second section is left inconsistent (because it expects more rows then there are elements in the source).

Possible solution is deleting both the rows at once

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: indexPath.row, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: indexPath.row, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
```